# How to prevent pasting text in ember input helper?

Tags: html, ember.js

I'm using ember input helper to get some value in the application. The text field should not allow any text to be pasted. (Something like re-enter some value)

I've just tried

```
{{input value=inputText onpaste="return false"}}
```

This didn't work. But in normal html, The following works.

```
<input value=inputText onpaste="return false">
```

But the problem here is no two-way binding (which supports in ember input helper).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need two way binding:

```
<input value={{inputText}} oninput={{action (mut inputText) value="target.value"}} onpaste="return false">
```

---

Sidenote: *Never* do this! This can be horrible to accessibility and user experience. It also never really works. You can always have browser plugins disabling this, or in this simple case people pasting by right click.